# Linux autostart application focus

Tags: linux, focus, autostart

Is it possible to have an application run by a autostart file like `.config/autostart/app.desktop` attain focus on start up? Window manager used is OpenBox, but it seems most window managers don't assign focus to autostart applications.

Comment: Openbox allows you to give focus to windows when launched according to the `<applications>` section in `rc.xml`. Have you explored that route? I don't launch apps using autostart and so can't say whether this will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wmtool` in `~/.config/openbox/autostart`:

```
wmtool -a [complete_or_partial_process_name] &
```

To give focus to Iceweasel:

```
wmtool -a iceweasel &
```

`wmtool` might not be included in your installation and have to be installed.